# PSQL Missing Highlight Syntax after Array expression

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I have noticed that the highlight missing after the `ARRAY` expression [ ].
The PSQL script can be run successfully but it's quite annoying.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY [ CONCAT('0', SUBSTRING(REGEXP_REPLACE(test.elec_num, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') FROM 3)) ] 
FROM test 
WHERE LENGTH(test.elec_num) > 10;
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the SQL language support that comes out of the box with Visual Studio Code is configured for [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL), instead of [PL/pgSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL) like Postgres implements. It looks like the single quotes are throwing the syntax highlighting off in your case.

I found a Postgres Extension, called [PostgreSQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres) that after installing, the syntax of your SQL above looks more appropriate (note, this is also after changing the language to `postgres`, which is added by this extension):

[image: Sql]

Comment: Installed! Thank you, that makes sense since VS Code's Microsoft product. (That's why default SQL should set as T-SQL)